# How do I insert chinese characters into MySQL from a sript?

Tags: mysql

I have the following script

```
set username utf8;
insert into tables values ('Active','活跃')
```

However after the script run, the inserted value for the chinese character is

`æ´»è·ƒ`

What did I miss here ?

Comment: did you create the table with UTF8?

Comment: `set username utf8;` – are you sure you meant `username` here, and not `set names utf8;` …?

Comment: I can insert chinese characters from my application but not the script. Lemme check your suggestion CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so that you have to change `Collation` to `Chinese`.

You can change that by here(below image)

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE big5 (BIG5 CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET BIG5);

mysql> INSERT INTO big5 VALUES (0xf9dc);

mysql> SELECT * FROM big5;
+------+
| big5 |
+------+
| 嫺  |
+------+
```

[MySQL `Big5` Chinese character set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-cjk.html#qandaitem-A-11-1-3)

[Read this as well](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-cjk.html)

Answer (score 0):

In database,Also set collation of fields to utf8_general_ci. If you can set collation of databas and tables to utg8_general_ci as well, that will even be better.